# How to read and upload a xls file using Spring framework?

Tags: java, excel, spring

I have an xls file, for example "abc.xls"; how can I read and upload this file using Spring?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spring MVC's [File upload support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) to get the file from browser to server, and then [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to extract the required data from it.